# Writing foldTerm from 'Data types ala Carte' in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to write the `foldTerm` function from [Data Types ala Carte](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf&ei=M33_T7iBNeOy2wXT8dyuBA&usg=AFQjCNHTd-wFnUQ0MfIxo8dMSVny-cyuww) in Scala.  Here's what I've got so far

```
def foldTerm[F[+_], A, B](e: Free[F, A], pure: A ⇒ B, imp: F[B] ⇒ B)(implicit F: Functor[F]): B =
  e.resume match { 
    case Right(a) ⇒ pure(a)
    case Left(x)  ⇒ imp(F.map(x)(foldTerm(_, pure, imp)))
}
```

This works, but since Scala cannot properly optimize tail recursion, it causes a SOE.  I've tried to fix it with `Trampoline` but have not had any luck so far.  I feel like I should be able to do this with the existing methods on `Free` but all my attempts have ended in frustration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Scala can properly eliminate tail recursive calls. But your method is not tail recursive. You can check it with the `@annotaion.tailrec` annotation.

```
@annotation.tailrec
def foldTerm[F[+_], A, B](e: Free[F, A], pure: A ⇒ B, imp: F[B] ⇒ B)(implicit F: Functor[F]): B =
  e.resume match { 
    case Right(a) ⇒ pure(a)
    case Left(x)  ⇒ imp(F.map(x)(foldTerm(_, pure, imp)))
}

<console>:19: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method foldTerm: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
           case Left(x)  ⇒ imp(F.map(x)(foldTerm(_, pure, imp)))
```

Your last call here is `imp` and not `foldTerm`.

Comment: Then why does he say that scala is not able to eliminate tail recursive calls?

Comment: Because Scala apply only one recursion optimization: tail call position. Thanks to its laziness Haskell can handle more recursion optimizations. You may be interested by this [link](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow)

Comment: I know that, but the OP said `"Scala cannot properly optimize tail recursion"` and that is not true. That is the reason for my answer.

Comment: As Yo Eight say, Scala can only optimize the simplest of tail calls.  It cannot optimize mutually recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this wasn't my problem after all. I was using a `ListT.fromList` on a large list and that is what was blowing the stack. Switching to using `StreamT` fixed the problem.